# Should I tell my co-authors that I don’t have any energy left for an undergrad dissertation that is taking forever?

Tags: mathematics, thesis

I have been working on my undergrad dissertation (which is a joint paper with two other authors) for about 7 months now. I have written a manuscript, but I keep on discovering bugs. Basically, I have no energy left for this project because of three reasons:

- bugs
- nothing I do seems to be enough to impress my advisors/co-authors
- I am the only undergrad in the group and my co-authors take on more of a mentoring role (general advice and ideas but they don’t write with me). So it gets really isolating and lonely at times because I’m basically working alone.

My co-authors have invested a good amount of time advising me, so I feel bad about the thought of giving up. I would continue if I had someone else to work more closely with me.

My question is, is it bad if I tell them that I don’t have any energy left for this project?

Comment: Your thesis is your own to write, you can't expect someone else to write it with you (although you should be some relevant feedback on it). On the other hand, if you mean that there is some joint paper that you are writing and your co-authors aren't contributing to it, then you should make that clearer in your question. In any case, the natural first step is to let your advisors know that you are struggling. It's not like the only two options are "continuing to suffer in silence" or "quitting the project".

Comment: My dissertation is a joint paper with two other people.

Comment: I suggest editing that information into your question. In any case, the key is communicating about your situation with your advisors.

Comment: Is the dissertation a requirement for you to graduate?

Comment: Regarding "not enough to impress" - are they actually saying that it isn't adequate (for graduation, publication, etc)?  Or is it that you're hoping for enthusiastic praise which they aren't giving?

Comment: Regarding "basically working alone": for better or for worse, this is pretty common for collaboration in mathematics.  It would be great to sit down with your co-author and tackle a problem or write a section, but logistically, you usually simply can't find enough hours in the intersection of your schedules.  So often instead you split up the project into chunks that you can write independently, and in your precious meeting time you focus on how the chunks should fit together.

Comment: What sort of program requires a months-long dissertation at the undergraduate level?

Comment: @JohnGordon: Mine required a yearlong project, either an individual thesis or a group "clinic".  It's not unheard of.

Comment: All non-engineering majors at Princeton require two ‘junior papers’ (one per semester) and a senior thesis to graduate. These are carried out under the supervision of an advisor.

Comment: The dissertation is a requirement for me to graduate. But I already submitted it and got my grade. However, I was not required to solve the entire problem in order to graduate, I only had to make good enough progress, which I did. Now, I am trying to refine my work and arrive at a complete solution in order to publish a paper. @NateEldredge

Comment: I was hoping for some appreciation of the time I spent working on the problem but I got none whatsoever @NateEldredge